# Web application in Azure - how to log errors?

Tags: .net-framework, azure, error-logging

I have a web application deployed to azure but I don't know how to log errors.

For testing purposes I have this ForceError method:

```
public string ForceError()
{
    throw new Exception("just a test exception");
    return "ok";
}
```

Which causes and error like this: "An error occurred while processing your request".

On Azure I enabled all Diagnostic logs like this to a storage container. But the error I forced does not appear in selected storage container.

Do you know what should I do to start logging all the errors from the application?

Comment: Why are you asking this question here instead of Stackoverflow?

Comment: I wasn't sure. But it isn't really about programming. It is about configuring the server in azure to log the errors

Comment: Did you find any solution?